# Expected value calculation problem

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

The problem is such that how to find expected value if variable y has the following distributn( kind of discrete)

$$p(y=0)=0.2$$ $$p(y=1)=0.3$$ $$p(y=2)=0.3$$ $$p(y>2)=0.2
$$

And for $y$ is $\textrm{Poisson}$ distributed, if $y>2$.

So i was confused by last term , i think we wouldnt consider cases when $y=3,4,5, \ldots$ so i am aware that it is possible to rewrite $p(y>2)$ as $1-p(y=1)-p(y=0)$ but then probabilities do not coincide. So how to find EY?

Comment: If you want to find P(y > 2) you also need to subtract P(y = 2) because these are discrete cases

Comment: Your probabilities do not add to $1$. And without further information about what exactly happens for $y>2$ there is no way you can compute $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: Sorry , i have noticed already, the only info available is that y is poisson distributed, but have does it help?

Comment: Expected value for a Poisson distribution is λ. Using the equation for a Poisson distribution you can solve for λ using the given info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X\sim Poi(\lambda)$. Then $P(X>2)=1-P(X=2)-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$.

$$ =1-e^{-\lambda}(\frac{\lambda^2}2+\lambda+1)=0.2$$

This equation cannot be solved algebraically. So use a calculator. Then

$$E(Y)=0\cdot 0.2+1\cdot 0.3+2\cdot 0.3+\sum_{x=3}^{\infty} x\cdot e^{-1.53504}\cdot \frac{1.53504^x}{x!}=1.597$$

Comment: The value for $E(Y)$ can be rounded to two decimal places. In this case you have $E(Y)=1.60$

Comment: Nice idea (+1), but 1.535 from where?

Comment: @BruceET It has been calculated by using the equation in the second line.

Comment: @Ilya You´re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The information that $Y \sim \mathsf{Pois}(\lambda)$ is crucial.
Then $P(Y = 0) = 0.2e^{-\lambda}$ can be solved to get $\lambda \approx 1.61$ (as @WaveX suggests; take logs). So $E(Y) \approx 1.61.$

But the probabilities in your problem seem to have been *severely* rounded.
Using the Poisson PDF with $\lambda = 1.61,$ I get the following
probabilities, where the last line is for $P(Y \ge 3):$

```
 y       P(Y=y)  Rounded
 0    0.1998876  0.2
 1    0.3218191  0.3
 2    0.2590643  0.3
 3+   0.2192290  0.2
```

Without the assumption that $Y$ has a Poisson distribution, you can say
that

$$E(Y) \ge 0(.2) + 1(.3) + 2(.3) + 3(.2) = 1.5,$$

but you don't have enough information to get an *exact* value.
Using the value $\lambda = 1.5$ with the Poisson PDF, the table above becomes:

```
cbind(x,pdf)
 y      P(Y-y)  Rounded
 0   0.2231302  0.2
 1   0.3346952  0.3
 2   0.2510214  0.3
 3+  0.1911532  0.2
```

So the much-rounded version of the distribution is the same as for $\lambda = 1.61.$

I honestly don't know what answer you should give to this flawed exercise.
You can give the first argument above with answer $E(Y) \approx 1.61;$
you can give the second argument with answer $E(Y) \approx 1.5;$
or you can give both along with a polite suggestion that the problem
is seriously flawed and you did what you could.

Below is a plot that illustrates the difference between the distributions
$\mathsf{Pois}(1.61)$ and $\mathsf{Pois}(1.5).$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding up to Bruce's response, you could take the given probabilities as *observed data distribution* and not real probabilities, and use the four of them, together with the true Poisson distribution you already know, to find a maximum likelihood estimator for $\lambda$.

Here is how: assume the given probabilities correspond to a data sample of size $N$, ($y_1,\dots,y_N$), such that there are $n_0$ observations of 0 arrivals ($y_k=0$), $n_1$ of 1 arrival, $n_2$ of 2 arrivals, and $n_3$ of more than 2 arrivals. So $n_0+n_1+n_2+n_3=N$ and $\frac{n_0}{N}=0.2$, $\frac{n_1}{N}=0.3$, $\frac{n_2}{N}=0.3$, $\frac{n_3}{N}=0.2$.

The likelihood function of the parameter $\lambda$ given the data is:
$$L(\lambda|y_1,\dots,y_k)=\prod_{k=1}^N P(Y=y_k|\lambda)=P(Y=0)^{n_0}P(Y=1)^{n_1}P(Y=2)^{n_2}P(Y>2)^{n_3}.$$

(I dropped the condition on $\lambda$ to simplify the notation.)

We take logarithm that preserves concavity and so does not change which $\lambda$ will give the maximum likelihood:

$$logL(\lambda|y_1,\dots,y_N)=n_0\log\left(P(Y=0)\right)+n_1\log\left(P(Y=1)\right)+n_2\log\left(P(Y=2)\right)+n_3\log\left(P(Y>2)\right).$$

Now we substitute each $P(Y=y)$ by its corresponding expression on $\lambda$ using the Poisson distribution formula:

$$logL(\lambda)=n_0\log\left(e^{-\lambda}\right)+n_1\log\left(e^{-\lambda}\lambda\right)+n_2\log\left(e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\right)+n_3\log\left(1-e^{-\lambda}\left(1+\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\right)\right).$$

Dividing by a positive constant does not change where the maximum of the function is located, so we divide both sides by $N$ (and substitute the $\frac{n_k}{N}$ by their corresponding probabilities given in the problem):

$$\frac{logL(\lambda)}{N}=0.2\log\left(e^{-\lambda}\right)+0.3\log\left(e^{-\lambda}\lambda\right)+0.3\log\left(e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\right)+0.2\log\left(1-e^{-\lambda}\left(1+\lambda+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\right)\right).$$

We take derivative and equate it to zero to solve for $\lambda$ and we find the MLE estimator given the data is:

$$\hat{\lambda}=1.60187.$$

Finally, for a Poisson distribution with arrival rate $\lambda$, $E(Y)=\lambda$, so you obtain the maximum likelihood estimator for the mean is

$$\hat{\mu}=1.60187.$$

Comment: Nice idea (+1), but without showing the method this is more Comment than Answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Bruce. I am new here and I was not sure on how deep or detailed the responses are expected to be (plus I don't have enough reputation to comment). I edited it now.

Comment: No worries. The boundary btw Comments and Answers is frequently blurred, _sometimes by me._ I'm sure OP (author of Question) will appreciate your careful update.